# URL gets truncated after # hash in the href

Tags: html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, hash, urlencode

I have a long URL which contains hash "#"  in it

**for example** 
"**something.com/frankyssssddsdfjsdflk?frank#content**"

```
<a href="http://something.com/frankyssssddsdfjsdflk?frank#content">Some Text Here</a>
```

When I clicnk the link in browser url get truncated after "**#**" hash symbol, it shows like:

"**something.com/frankyssssddsdfjsdflk?frank**"

When I changed the # with "**`%26`**" URL encode , the URL then works fine for Firfox, but not for IE and Chrome.

Please suggest!!

Comment: please could you provide the html for the anchor

Comment: you mean the HTML of <a href="">?? I updated the code to add HTML of HREF

Comment: It changes *in the browser* or you mean you're not receiving the `#...` part *on the server*?

Comment: m not sure of server... m just chekcing on my broswer... so if I clcik on link the URL get truncated after "#"... but if I copy and paste the full URL on browsers, it loads the correct page

Comment: Do you have some sort of js bootstrap / library affecting your links?

Comment: no... its a simple HTML CSS page,

Comment: You need to provide the ACTUAL URL to allow others to reproduce this. The problem does not exist in general.